# how to write REGEXP_CONTAINS for 2 different keys of the same array in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have 3 documents in my Couchbase db :-

```
{
    "appId": "f1606a90-c96f-4db9-8e5f-9f0b6d2d2182",
    "assignedTo": "Sweta",
    "attributes": [
       {
         "activity": "Supplier Migration Request"
       },
       {
         "comments": "great work"
       },
       {
         "assignedTo": "Sweta"
       }
    ],
   "status": "InProgress",
   "task": {
     "details": {
        "subject": "RE: Complexpromo-vnagara1-7708-cz",
      },
     "taskType": "mail"
   },
   "taskId": "142af79d-123f-4990-a9aa-5e3e4ea7723c",
   "type": "task"
},
{
   "appId": "f1606a90-c96f-4db9-8e5f-9f0b6d2d2182",
   "assignedTo": "Santhosh",
   "attributes": [
      {
        "activity": "Supplier Migration Request"
      },
      {
        "comments": "work"
      },
      {
        "assignedTo": "Santhosh"
      }
    ],
   "status": "InProgress",
   "task": {
     "details": {
        "subject": "RE: Complexpromo-vnagara1-7708-cz",
      },
     "taskType": "mail"
   },
   "taskId": "242af79d-123f-4990-a9aa-5e3e4ea7723c",
   "type": "task"
},
{
   "appId": "f1606a90-c96f-4db9-8e5f-9f0b6d2d2182",
   "assignedTo": "Santhosh",
   "attributes": [
      {
        "activity": "Supplier Request"
      },
      {
        "comments": "your work is not completed"
      },
      {
        "assignedTo": "Santhosh"
      }
    ],
   "status": "New",
   "task": {
     "details": {
        "subject": "RE: task-detail-7708-cz",
      },
     "taskType": "mail"
   },
   "taskId": "342af79d-123f-4990-a9aa-5e3e4ea7723c",
   "type": "task"
}
```

I am looking for a query which give me the data who has a keyword "work" in the "comments" of the attributes and a keyword "Migration" in the "activity" of the attributes section.

I have tried writing a query :-

```
select wf.* from workflow wf UNNEST attributes attr where wf.appId="f1606a90-c96f-4db9-8e5f-9f0b6d2d2182" AND wf.type="task" and REGEXP_CONTAINS(attr.activity, "Migration+.*") and REGEXP_CONTAINS(attr.comments, "work+.*") and REGEXP_CONTAINS(wf.status, "InProgress+.*") limit 5;
```

Expected Result :-

```
{
    "appId": "f1606a90-c96f-4db9-8e5f-9f0b6d2d2182",
    "assignedTo": "Sweta",
    "attributes": [
       {
         "activity": "Supplier Migration Request"
       },
       {
         "comments": "great work"
       },
       {
         "assignedTo": "Sweta"
       }
    ],
   "status": "InProgress",
   "task": {
     "details": {
        "subject": "RE: Complexpromo-vnagara1-7708-cz",
      },
     "taskType": "mail"
   },
   "taskId": "142af79d-123f-4990-a9aa-5e3e4ea7723c",
   "type": "task"
},
{
   "appId": "f1606a90-c96f-4db9-8e5f-9f0b6d2d2182",
   "assignedTo": "Santhosh",
   "attributes": [
      {
        "activity": "Supplier Migration Request"
      },
      {
        "comments": "work"
      },
      {
        "assignedTo": "Santhosh"
      }
    ],
   "status": "InProgress",
   "task": {
     "details": {
        "subject": "RE: Complexpromo-vnagara1-7708-cz",
      },
     "taskType": "mail"
   },
   "taskId": "242af79d-123f-4990-a9aa-5e3e4ea7723c",
   "type": "task"
}
```

As the first 2 documents is having both "Migration" in the keyword "activity" and "work" in the keyword "comments" so the answer should be first 2 documents.
where as the 3rd document is not "Migration" in the keyword "activity" so it will not be selected even though it has "work" in the keyword "comments".

Any idea how to get the expected result? or how to improvise my current query? any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT wf.*
FROM workflow wf
WHERE wf.appId = "f1606a90-c96f-4db9-8e5f-9f0b6d2d2182"
      AND wf.type = "task"
      AND ANY attr IN wf.attributes SATISFIES REGEXP_CONTAINS(attr.activity, "Migration+.*") END
      AND ANY attr IN wf.attributes SATISFIES REGEXP_CONTAINS(attr.comments, "work+.*") END
      AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(wf.status, "InProgress+.*")
LIMIT 5;
```

Use of UNNEST nothing but self JOIN with main query each array element. Use UNNEST if you need to project qualified ARRAY element as   of JOIN.

Use ANY if you want match one of the ARRAY element as predicate and project main document.